# Stored procedure for Login Application

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the user details like
id
fname
lname
role
branch
email
password

I have a stored procedure for the login validation which takes the values of `email` and `password`, validates and send out the success message.
The validation is working now. I need to fetch the values of `fname, lname, role` and `branch` too.

Here is the code:

```
USE [Project]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[usp_loginuser]
(@Email varchar(100),
@password varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @msg nvarchar(2048)
SET NOCOUNT ON
--select * from dbo.userdetails where email=@userEmail and pwd=@password

   BEGIN TRY

        Declare @flag bit
        SET @flag = 0

        IF EXISTS(Select *  from userdetails
        where ltrim(rtrim(email)) = ltrim(rtrim(@Email)) AND ltrim(rtrim(pwd)) = ltrim(rtrim(@password))
        AND isactive = 1)
        BEGIN 
        SET @flag =1;
        END

        ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @flag =0;
        END

        SELECT @flag [IsSuccess]


   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
          SET @msg = error_message()  
      RAISERROR (@msg, 16, 1)
   END CATCH

SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: fetch the values as output? can you share the output format you are expecting?

Comment: fetch the values of fname ,lname,branch and role for that particular login. because these details will be required in the next page after i login.

Comment: SELECT fname, lname, branch FROM userdetails before the END

Comment: @JoeTaras is this enough to take the values to the next page?

Comment: If you put that SELECT the output of your SP is that, so you can use out of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[usp_loginuser]
    (@Email varchar(100),
     @password varchar(100),
     @fname varchar(100) output, 
     @lname varchar(100) output
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @msg nvarchar(2048)
SET NOCOUNT ON
   BEGIN TRY

        Declare @flag bit
        SET @flag = 0

        IF EXISTS(Select @fname = fname, @lname = lname from userdetails
        where ltrim(rtrim(email)) = ltrim(rtrim(@Email)) AND ltrim(rtrim(pwd)) = ltrim(rtrim(@password))
        AND isactive = 1)
        BEGIN 
            SET @flag =1;
        END

        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @flag =0;
        END

        SELECT @flag [IsSuccess], @fname, @lname


   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
          SET @msg = error_message()  
      RAISERROR (@msg, 16, 1)
   END CATCH

SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: You have to declare the output variables as in "ALTER Procedure" statement and assing the values like in if statement in select query and return the same variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRY

        Declare @flag bit
        SET @flag = 0

        IF EXISTS(Select *  from userdetails
        where ltrim(rtrim(email)) = ltrim(rtrim(@Email)) AND ltrim(rtrim(pwd)) = ltrim(rtrim(@password))
        AND isactive = 1)
        BEGIN 
        SET @flag =1;
        END

        ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @flag =0;
        END

        SELECT fname, lname, role, branch  from userdetails
        where ltrim(rtrim(email)) = ltrim(rtrim(@Email)) AND ltrim(rtrim(pwd)) = ltrim(rtrim(@password))

   END TRY
```

If you get an empty data set, its a failure else success

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable "@Email".

Comment: are you getting the error if you remove the select statement at the end also?